# Filtering an array based object's property inside a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following two simple objects:

```
clinics: [
    { 
        id: 1,
        name: 'New Hampshire Veterinarian Clinic',
        plans: [
            'handle123',
            'handle567',
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Westminster Moltchester Clinic',
        plans: [
            'handle123',
            'handle789',
        ]
    }
],
animals: [
    { 
        id: 1,
        handle: 'handle123',
        name: 'Cat',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        handle: 'handle567',
        name: 'Dog',
    },
    {
            id: 3,
            handle: 'haneld789',
            name: 'Horse'
    }
],
```

I have the following method:

```
updateAnimals(selectedOption, id) {
}
```

where `selectedOption` is one object from the `clinics` array.

I want to filter the second array so it only contains the handles mentioned in the selected option, but I'm having trouble with the arguments. I want to achieve something like this:

```
updateAnimals(selectedOption, id) {
    let filteredAnimals = this.animals.filter(function({id, handle, name}) {
       // Access the selectedOption here so I can use it to filter
    });
}
```

But I'm not sure how to access the selected option inside the function...
Or is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use selectedOption just like any other variable available in a scope by simply using it directly `selectedOption.something`:

```js
updateAnimals(selectedOption, id) {
    let filteredAnimals = this.animals.filter({ handle } => {
       return selectedOption.plans.includes(handle)
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow.. my problem was I was attaching selectedOption.handle to another variable before the filter... or at least I think so, it was so simple just accessing it normally. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
updateAnimals(selectedOption, id) {
  const handles=selectedOption.plans;
  let result= animals.filter(animal=>handles.includes(animal.handle)); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.